# Moodle: how do I set default blocks into custom region in new courses?

Tags: php, moodle

I have a Moodle site with custom regions, namely 'top' and 'bottom'. I would like to automatically add an HTML block to all new courses in the top region.

I have these in my `config.php`, and the block is added to the new courses, but in the wrong place, to `side-pre` region... How can I change this to add the block to the top region?

```
'course' => array(
    'file' => 'course.php',
    'regions' => array('side-pre', 'top', 'bottom'),
    'defaultregion' => 'bottom',
    'options' => array('nonavbar'=>false),

$CFG->defaultblocks_override = 'html';
$CFG->defaultblocks_site = 'html';
$CFG->defaultblocks_social = 'html';
$CFG->defaultblocks_topics = 'html';
$CFG->defaultblocks_weeks = 'html';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from the docs ([Default block layout for new courses](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Block_layout)):

> `$CFG->defaultblocks_topics =  'participants,tags,admin:messages,online_users,recent_activity';`
>
> Note how the colon is used to separate those blocks appearing on the left, from those appearing on the right.

It seems like you would have to use a colon. I looked at the function code, that parses this string (in `lib/blocklib.php`, function `blocks_parse_default_blocks_list`, Moodle 2.4) and I think it could only handle left or right regions (`side-pre` and `side-post`). For an hackish solution, you could change this lines of code (in `lib/blocklib.php`):

```
define('BLOCK_POS_LEFT',  'side-pre');
```

To:

```
define('BLOCK_POS_LEFT',  'top');
```

But I think a better solution is the use of "sticky" blocks (Moodle `> 2.3` required). Have a look at this [doc](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Block_settings#Making_a_block_sticky_throughout_the_whole_site). Here are the different steps:

1. Add the block in the front page;
2. Edit the configuration of the block. On the section *Where this block appears* select *Display throughout the entire site*;
3. Select default region, as desired (in your case, *top* or *bottom*).
4. Now you have to show the block only on courses. Enter a course. Edit the block (in the course) and on *Display on page types* select *Any course page*.

Now the blocks will appear only on course pages (and not on the front page).

Credits: [Re: Block in all Courses in Moodle 2.0](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=170353#p747238). I personally tested it on a Moodle 2.4 installation.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly sticky blocks aren't a possibility for me, as I want to add an HTML block to every page, but with different content... Editing the blocklib.php works beautifully for me!

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)